# Dynamically Creating Meta Titles from Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't seem to find a bit of code directly related to what I'm trying to accomplish, and that might be because there is some much much easier way to accomplish this task.

Basically I'd like to structure and change en-mass our company website Meta Titles. I'd like to build a title structure where I pull off columns from our database for -manufacturer sku- and -manufactuer & model-, then pump out dynamically created titles in this format:

(Manufacturer Sku) - (Manufacturer & Model) (Upsell/Call to Action) | (Company Name)

Now the Title should be less than 70 characters so the first three "cells" are variable character lengths, and the company name cell is always set.

So basically my thinking is that I need to make like 20 (Upsell) options of differing character lengths, so that when I combine columns I can get excel to pick the longest upsell option that makes the whole meta Title fit under 70 characters.

Most of the skus and models have differing character lengths but i'd like to be able to get in all of these elements because I think that would make for the best Meta Titles.

Am I making this too difficult for myself?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to show us what you have tried already, a sample of your code and input and desired output, along with a distinct problem statement. The way your question is currently structured, it is hard to tell exactly what you want help with. Please read [ask].

Comment: any sample data to start with?